# SQL Loader - How do I escape an terminating character

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Friends,

I have had a client data sent to me in that is requested to have fields terminated by '|'

Problem is, some of the filed values also have the "|" as a character that we need to preserve.

Problem rows in my datafile look like this (the '|' in the addres "1|34-36 ..." is the issue)

```
    ID  |   Address                |UPDATEDATE
  1423  |   1|34-36 White Street   |02/01/199
```

my .ctl looks like this

```
options(errors=1000)
load data
into table client_address APPEND
fields terminated by '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ID          INTEGER EXTERNAL,
```

Comment: There is no way you can reliably parse that file unless the values that contain the delimiter e.g. use quotes or some other way to "escape" the delimiter.

Comment: And you can't get them to send it with a different separator?  Like ~?

Answer (score 1):

If all fields in data file are width-aligned, you could use this .ctl file:

```
load data
into table client_address APPEND
fields terminated by '~'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
line         BOUNDFILLER,
ID           "to_number(trim(substr(:line,1,8)))",
Address      "trim(substr(:line,10,26))",
UPDATEDATE   "to_date(trim(substr(:line,37)),'mm/dd/yyyy')"
)
```

---

**EDIT :**
If fields are not width-aligned, but `Address` is the only field which can contain `'|'` char inside, then use this .ctl file

```
load data
into table client_address APPEND
fields terminated by '~'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
line         BOUNDFILLER,
ID           "to_number(trim(regexp_substr(:line,'^[^|]*')))",
Address      "trim(regexp_replace(:line,'^[^|]*\|(.*)\|[^|]*$','\1'))",
UPDATEDATE   "to_date(trim(regexp_substr(:line,'[^|]*$')),'mm/dd/yyyy')"
)
```